# How can I modify html form or associated php code behavior so that Firefox does not cache the captcha image upon clicking browser back button?

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a html form with security image (captcha) with code based on phpformgen, that behaves differently for MS Internet Explorer and Firefox.

When there is a field form error, an error message pops up. To get back to the form to correct it, back button in the browser is clicked.
                                                                                          Now, after back button is clicked:

1. IE 10 will display cached(already entered) data so that user does not have to retype all of it, and importantly, there is a NEW captcha displayed that user needs to type in. This is what I want to happen, I think.
2. Firefox 25  will also display already entered fields but it will not change the captcha !

How can I modify html form or associated php code behavior so that Firefox does not cache the captcha image upon clicking browser back button and behave like IE10 ?

Answer (score 0):

In the form tag you can add autofill off, 
autofill='false';

That should do it.